# Trouble adding a USB drive for additional storage

Tags: raspbian

I have mounted a USB drive to my Raspberry Pi but I have no idea why the files automatically delete themselves when I reboot my Pi. I followed instructions to mount my drive to a specific folder but nothing ever seems to stay on the drive after I restart it. I think it has something to do with an orphan clean... I found this in one of the Kernel log files but don't know why this is happening. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

This is the part of the kernel log where the usb is mentioned:

[image: kernel_log_file]

Comment: You have to add references when you refer to something, example: "I followed instructions" what instruction, url... and "I found this in one of the Kernel log" add a bit of the kernel log that you think is suspicious. So the keyword is, facts, that is going to get you assistance to find the problem. And could you also section the text into paragraphs so it is easy to read.